# How to include headers in RESTDataSource request?

Tags: javascript, apollo-server

I'm trying to use apollo RESTDataSource to wrap my rest api. I need to pass some headers to the api call.

I'm following the example from the docs: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/features/data-sources#intercepting-fetches

This is my code:

```
  willSendRequest(request: RequestOptions) {
    console.log(`request 1: ${JSON.stringify(request)}`);
    request.headers.set('Authorization', this.context.authorization);
    console.log(`request 2: ${JSON.stringify(request)}`);
  }
```

I'm expecting the headers to contain 'Authorization'. But it's always empty.

The log from the above code:

```
request 1: {"method":"POST","path":"partnerinvoices","body":{"command": "input","params":{},"headers":{}}
request 2: {"method":"POST","path":"partnerinvoices","body":{"command":"input","params":{},"headers":{}}
```

I can override body and params in `willSendRequest` method without any problem.

Answer (score 6):

There are few ways that you could implement this,

within your `Datasources` class that extends RESTDataSource set the headers before request is being made

```
willSendRequest(request) {
 request.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer .....')
}
```

or as a third argument in the datasource method (post, get, put, ...)

```
this.post('endpoint', {}, { headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ...' } })
```

Comment: The first implementation you provided is the exact same one @clothoo didn't get working. I am running into the same issue and it seems that the header just won't get set. Have you found any better solution than adding headers in every request?

Comment: If you are using apollo/datasource-rest version 5 or 6 now, the function has changed to:
this.post('endpoint', { headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ...' } })
i.e. only 2 function parameters now, combine your url params with your headers

Answer (score 1):

It is super important, if you are using Typescript, that you match the original signature of the `willSendRequest` method:

```js
protected willSendRequest?(request: RequestOptions): ValueOrPromise<void>;
```

(Link to the [docs](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/blob/4124dd2c23cb16f539e163a7d2d1b99cfb2f6041/packages/apollo-datasource-rest/src/RESTDataSource.ts#L72))

So, make sure the method looks like this:

```
    protected willSendRequest?(request: RequestOptions): ValueOrPromise<void> {
        request.headers.set("Authorization", this.context.authorization);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `request.headers.get('Authorization')` to get your desired data. Using `JSON.stringify` will not give you the headers values as it is not a object literal.

```
willSendRequest(request: RequestOptions) {
    console.log(`request 1: ${request.headers.get('Authorization')}`);
    request.headers.set('Authorization', this.context.authorization);
    console.log(`request 2: ${request.headers.get('Authorization')}`);
  }
```